# Writing JSTL code for JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, charts, jstl

I have a stand alone JavaScript which would plot a graph.

```
 <script type="text/javascript"     src="/GraphicalPortlet-portlet/js/amcharts.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/GraphicalPortlet-portlet/js/raphael.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
var chart;
var chartData = [
             {country:"Tâches",a:25}, //this is the chart data
             {country:"UK",a:25},
             {country:"Fran\u00E7ais ",a:25 } ];

    window.onload = function() {
    chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.categoryField = "country";

    var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
    graph.labelText="[[value]]";
    graph.valueField = "a";
    graph.type = "column";

//some other components 
    var valAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valAxis.stackType = "regular";
    valAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
    valAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    chart.addValueAxis(valAxis);

    var catAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
    catAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
    catAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
    catAxis.gridPosition = "start";

              //this is the actual plotting of graph
    chart.write("chartdiv");
}
```

My questions

1)how can I write a JSTL code for this JS so the other JSP's can include my JSTL and the graph would be plotted for them.

2)If the client needs to send the data and not use my dummy data. How would I go about it and alter my JSTL?

The whole idea is that the different JSP's should not duplicate my JS code. Instead just include one liner of JSTL tag which would have this JS code.

Comment: You can easily include a js file in a JSP file. You basically just include the file like you included the other javascript files. Now for sending data, you need some kind of form to send a GET request or POST request. Then you can set variables in your javascript files, you can use a for loop or whatever to get the parameters.

Comment: @Matt Thanks for the reminder that I could easily include my JS in other places. 
Can you put some light on how the JSP's could send variables to my JS library? Any psedo code or cod link?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing. It look like that you're mixing JSTL with something else. Please read [our JSTL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) to learn what it *actually* is.

As far as I understand, the functional requirement is that you need to supply server-side variables to JavaScript. This can be done in several ways.

1. Let JSP print it as a global JS variable:

   ```
   <script>var data = ${someDataInJSONFormat};</script>
   ```

   Where `${someDataInJSONFormat}` is been prepared by a preprocessing servlet:

   ```
   request.setAttribute("someDataInJSONFormat", someDataInJSONFormat);
   ```

   And let your JS access it on window load:

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
       doSomethingWith(data);
   }
   ```
2. Let JS retrieve it by Ajax:

   ```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
           var data = eval('(' + xhr.responseText + ')');
           doSomethingWith(data);
       }
   }
   xhr.open('GET', 'someServletURL', true);
   xhr.send(null);
   ```

   where `someServletURL` is the URL to a servlet which returns the data:

   ```
   response.setContentType("application/json");
   response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
   response.getWriter().write(someDataInJSONFormat);
   ```

You can use a JSON library such as [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert Java objects to a JSON string.